# Make a Plot Bar from Pandas multilevel dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, plot

I'm having troubles trying to make a bar plot from a pandas dataframe, which should be easy but I can't make it work.
I have a dataframe that looks like that:

|  | Data A | Data B | Data C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| timestamp |  |  |  |
| 06:54:00 | 0.1 | 0.2 | 0.3 |

But instead of 3 columns with Data, I have 99.
The point is that I am trying to do a bar plot representing in the x axis the different Data and in the y axis the values.

I tried with:

```
p = data.hvplot.bar(x = 'Data', y = 'Units', rot = 90)
```

And

```
p = data.plot(kind='bar', title="Data", figsize=(15, 10), legend=True, fontsize=12)
```

But none of them are working, and I think that the problem comes from the format of my dataframe, because of the column 'timestamp'.
However, I haven't manage to delete it, I tried:

```
data = data.droplevel('timestamp')
```

And:

```
data = data.drop(['timestamp'], axis=1)
```

But none of them are working. Could someone please give me a hand with that?

Comment: How did you get this data? is `timestamp` a cell? or is it the index? I don't think it's second-level column tbh.

Comment: Looks like timestamp is an index

Comment: Can you include the output of `data.iloc[:,:3].head().to_dict()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally managed to solve it.

What I did was:

`new_df = data.melt(var_name="Data")`

To get a new dataframe without the timestamp.
Then:

`titles = new_df['Data'].to_list()`

`values = new_df['value'].to_list()`

To get two lists, one with the titles and another one with the values.

And then I plotted the chart with the following code:

```
p = figure(x_range=titles, height=500, width=1500, title="Unit",
           toolbar_location=None, tools="")

p.vbar(x=titles, top=values, width=0.6)

p.xgrid.grid_line_color = None
p.xaxis.major_label_orientation = "vertical"
p.y_range.start = 0
```

Thank you all,

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
new_df = df.melt(var_name="Data")
new_df.plot(kind='bar', x='Data', y='value')
```

[image]